# Switch to Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics

I've been using Google Analytics for a few years now which I think is using Universal Analytics property (the property starts with `UA-`).

A few months back I migrated/added GA4 property on the back of an email from Google. But I noticed in my HTML pages are still using the old `UA-` property for tag manager. Do I just switch these over to use the new GA4 property? Can I then delete the old `UA-` property?